AVPlayer Won’t Play .ts Video Stream, But It Works in VLC
I’ve been trying to play a .ts (Transport Stream) video file in my SwiftUI app using AVPlayer, but I’m running into issues. The .ts file plays fine in VLC and other media players, so I’m confused as to why it won’t work in my iOS app.
I created a SwiftUI app and used AVPlayer and AVPlayerViewController to try to stream the video from the .ts URL.
The URL is valid and works when I test it in VLC, so I know the link isn’t broken.
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var player: AVPlayer?
    let url = URL(string: "http://alibaba.gotoplucky.com:23000/live/Damianomaca/EfYpS6xSVy/260.ts")!
    let url3 = URL(string: "http://alibaba.gotoplucky.com:23000/live/Damianomaca/EfYpS6xSVy/26060.ts")!
    @State var isVPlayerOut = false
    var body: some View {
        
        Button {
            isVPlayerOut.toggle()
        } label: {
            Text("Open Video")
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $isVPlayerOut) {
            VideoPlayerView(url: url3)
                
        }
        
    
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}



struct VideoPlayerView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    let url: URL
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> AVPlayerViewController {
        let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
        let player = AVPlayer(url: url)
        print("\(url)")
        player.play()
        playerViewController.player = player
        return playerViewController
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: AVPlayerViewController, context: Context) {
        // Optional updates
    }
}


I would appreciate any suggestions how to play this ts file Thanks!

You could try wrapping the ts URLs in a m3u8 playlist file and play that.  I'm not sure if that would like the URLs in the playlist, in which case you'd need to look at AVAssetResourceLoader.

Note Apple requires https connection. To use http, you need to set the "NSAppTransportSecurity"
in your Info.plist to allow http connection to the server. Have you done that?

yes I set NSAppTransportSecurity allow arbitrary load to YES

Note, using your code I can play .mp4 files.
I just downloaded VLC, but I could not play your .ts files using it.

Yes that why I’m looking for a solution how to play ts file

you say The .ts file plays fine in VLC..., but I cannot play these files on VLC. Are you sure you can play them using VLC?

Yes vlc no problem at all I can play both link

Wondering if there is any third party API or similar that can stream video other than use avplayar

You could use VLCKit in your app.


"The .ts file plays fine in VLC and other media players, so I’m confused as to why it won’t work in my iOS app."

AVPlayer expects an M3U8 playlist file which lists the .ts file path inside.
Some steps you can try...
(1) Create the playlist dynamically 
By using a String to contain the playlist's text.
let my_string_m3u8 = """
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:VOD
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:0
#EXT-X-VERSION:4
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0

#EXTINF:0.0,
http://alibaba.gotoplucky.com:23000/live/Damianomaca/EfYpS6xSVy/26060.ts

#EXT-X-ENDLIST
"""

(2) Save text with .M3U8 extension 
According to Hacking With Swift
you can save a text file (the M3U8 data) using:
let tmpFileURL = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("my_test_stream.m3u8")

do 
{ try my_string_m3u8.write(to: tmpFileURL, atomically: true, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) } 
catch 
{
    // failed to write file – 
    // is bad permissions, bad filename, missing permissions, 
    // or more likely it can't be converted to the encoding
}

Also consider saving M3U8 as binary (instead of text), if still not working to show playback.
alternate version from this reference (Answer):
let tmpFileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath:NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent("my_test_stream").appendingPathExtension("m3u8")
let wasFileWritten = (try? data.write(to: tmpFileURL, options: [.atomic])) != nil

if !wasFileWritten{ print("File was NOT saved") }

Result: Should be a file in your app's temp directory called my_test_stream.m3u8.
(3) Try doing some video playback 
Where...
let url4 = URL(string: "path-to-your-temp-dir-m3u8-file")!

Could then be used as:
let player = AVPlayer(url: url4)
print("\(url4)")
player.play()

Hopefully you'll now get some playback...
